# puppeter select checkbox in table based on inner text

Tags: dom, puppeteer

I want to select a checkbox with Innertext of dog but for every row is composed of table

```
checkbox | Dog <============ composed of table
checkbox | Cat <============ composed of table
```

and the DOM element of the site is

```
<div class="grid-table-body">
  <div class="grid-table-row">
    <table class="table-grid">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="grid-cell">
            <div class="grid-checker" unselectable="on">
            </div>
          </td>
          <td class="grid-td-1>
            <div class="grid-col-1" unselectable="on">
              Dog
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      <tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-table-row">
    <table class="table-grid">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="grid-cell">
            <div class="grid-checker" unselectable="on">
            </div>
          </td>
          <td class="grid-td-1>
            <div class="grid-col-1" unselectable="on">
              Cat
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      <tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't know what to add in

```
let pageContent = await page.evaluate(() => document.getElementsByClassName("grid-table-body"));
```

Comment: What checkbox? There's no checkbox in your example HTML structure. Perhaps you mean a cell with inner text "Dog"?

Comment: @pavelsaman that's why I'm confused it has a checkbox in the site but not in the HTML structure. Or can I just tell puppeteer to click the row with the text of dog?

Comment: The checkbox could be added by JS, so you won't see it in HTML page source view, only in the DOM.

Comment: @pavelsaman so is there a way I can use puppeteer on this site?

Comment: You certainly can. But I think the answer to this question doesn't answer your previous question.

Comment: @Newboy11, you should inspect the page to look at the DOM and then find how to pick the checkbox element.